# use dynamic values in map/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I read about the [`Ecto.Query.API.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#map/2) function and I have a scenario where i have to use it.

Query is is like this:

```
  from p in model,
    where: p.id == 1,
    select: map(p, [:id, :inserted_by, customer: [:id, :first_name]])
```

so instead of `id` and `inserted_by` which are hard coded and `id` and `first_name`. I want to use dynamic values in a list like this

```
  [:id, :inserted_by, :first_name]
```

I tried using the `^` operator by saving a list in a variable. but it gives error `cannot use outside of match clause`
How can i change the query for dynamic values?
like this

```
  select: map(p, [^dynamic_value, customer: ^dynamic_value])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official `Ecto` documentation answers this question literally by it’s second sentence:

> [`Ecto.Query.API.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#map/2) can also be used to dynamically select fields:
>
> ```
> fields = [:title, :body]
> from p in Post, select: map(p, ^fields)
> ```

Which in your case would be:

```
dynamic_value = [:id, :inserted_by, customer: [:id, :first_name]]

from p in model,
where p.id == 1,
select: map(p, ^dynamic_value)
```

The issue with defining `dynamic_value` upfront is: `from` is a macro in a nutshell, it has a complicated logic inside and it accepts the prepared AST.